# Laravel command not found. But it is added to my $PATH on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So I know there are alot of simmular issues but none if them are exactly the same,

I want to start my first laravel project but, my terminal tells me command not found,

I installed composer from the website and when I run composer I can see that it works perfectally with no issue, when running `composer global require "laravel/installer"` I get this in response :

```
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
Using version ^4.2 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating autoload files
9 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
```

This tells me that laravel is indeed installed but has not updates but when I run command `laravel` the response is `laravel: command not found`,

I have added composer to my $PATH already.

This is why I am posting this issue because all the posts I find says to add composer to your $PATH but mine is already but its still a issue.

PHP is also installed on my machine

I am running linux Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: I havent heard about a laravel command, but you have php artisan command, so if it says laravel is installed then just try and run php artisan serve

Comment: you do have Laravel commands for creating an application.

Comment: Does `composer create-project laravel/laravel your-app-name` work?

Comment: _but, my terminal tells me command not found,_ **What** command gives this error. ALWAYS show ALL the error message and not just a summary

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) as you were requested to do on registration
and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and 
how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @dz0nika according to my tutorial I am following when I am suppose to use laravel new <project name> to make a new project but when I used that command I got the command not found, I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImtZ5yENzgE&list=WL&index=1&t=312s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll write the answer here so you can close the question. As [@geertjanknapen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9636400/geertjanknapen) said in the comment if you can install your project the run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel your-app-name
cd /your-app-name
php artisan serve
```

You must have a local server running also, once you have run `php artisan serve` then just go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ and you'll see Laravel's home screen. (NOTE 8000 is the default port, so put yours there if you've changed it).

Comment: Thank you, I dont know why that struggled so much